# Accessing Dom Attributes in Dojo Widgets

Tags: dojo

I've defined a widget in my template, for example:

I can't get the title text to be set programmatically.  I've tried many things that I kinda pseudo thought of but none work:

```
domStyle.set(this. , "display", '{ float: left }');
this.feetSelectContainer.display =  "float: 'left'";

<div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="someDivContainer1">....></div>
</div>
```

it's also saying this.someDivContainer1 is undefined..So I tried changing it to just an id:

```
    domStyle.set(this.someDivContainer1.id, "display", '{ float: "left"}');
dojo.attr(dojo.byId("someDivContainer1 "), "display", '{ float: "left"}');
```

don't know what else to try or how to do this through dojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up two style attributes: `display` and `float`

Use

```
domStyle.set(this.someDivContainer1, 'display', 'block');
```

or

```
domStyle.set(this.someDivContainer1, 'float', 'left');
```

Comment: already tried that, actually I was doing that before this post and it was not working.  But let me try something again though.  I changed the attach point to be id instead, so domStyle might work now.

Comment: thing that bugs me the most is trying to find the signature of these in Webstorm, aptana, etc.  When you try to get intellisense to tell you this set method's sig, it gives you a list of all classes that have a set method because it doesn't know.